# Cannot insert 'football' into column that has NULL as its value

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-update

I am unable to add text to column if it has the value NULL. It says (1 row(s) affected) but it still says NULL. But it works to insert text into column if there is already a value present. Ex. 'anything'

ProductGroup_Keywords(varchar(max), null)

I tried these 2 routes below

```
`Update [dbo].[Category]
 SET ProductGroup_Keywords = ProductGroup_Keywords + 'football'
 WHERE Category_ID = 101`

'Update [dbo].[Category]
 SET ProductGroup_Keywords = convert(nvarchar(max),ProductGroup_Keywords) + 'football'
 WHERE Category_ID = 101'
```

I then tried to just set it like below but it still said NULL

```
'Update [dbo].[Category]
 SET ProductGroup_Keywords = 'football'
 WHERE ProductGroup_Keywords = 101'
```

Please help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Update [dbo].[Category] 
 SET ProductGroup_Keywords = coalesce( ProductGroup_Keywords, '')  + 'football' 
 WHERE Category_ID = 101'
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a CASE statement:

```
 Update [dbo].[Category] 
 SET ProductGroup_Keywords = CASE 
                                WHEN ProductGroup_Keywords IS NULL THEN 'football'
                                ELSE ProductGroup_Keywords + 'football'
                             END  
 WHERE Category_ID = 101'
```

Or ISNULL rather than COALESCE...

```
 Update [dbo].[Category] 
 SET ProductGroup_Keywords = ISNULL( ProductGroup_Keywords, '')  + 'football' 
 WHERE Category_ID = 101'
```

Important thing is what @JoeStefanelli said: `x + NULL = NULL`